# How to decode Play Integrity response for a debug app (not released)

Tags: android, api, debugging, playback, integrity

like many other devs, I have a debug version of my Android application : not released on the Play Store.

I am implementing Play Integrity API (migrating from Safety Net).

After getting a valid response from the Play Integrity API, I should decode the token.

From the documentation I should do this next :

```
   // base64OfEncodedDecryptionKey is provided through Play Console.
   var decryptionKeyBytes: ByteArray = Base64.decode(base64OfEncodedDecryptionKey, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

The issue is that since it is a debug app I can't get `base64OfEncodedDecryptionKey` from the Play Store.

So how should I decode the Play Integrity token response in my not released app ?

Thanks,

Comment: Having the same issue, our app is released outside of the playstore and we can neither decode Play Integrity's response from neither debug nor release builds, because in Google's infinite wisdom, they decided to only provide the option to get both verification and decryption keys on play-store released apps.